# Why do the scalars always occupy the coset they do?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, supergravity, kaluza-klein

If I reduce a $D$-dimensional theory on a $d$-dimensional manifold $M_d$, then I will be left with some reduced, effectively $(D-d)$-dimensional theory with some global symmetry group $G$. In general, the scalar manifold is the coset $G/K(G)$, where $K(G)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $G$.

Some examples:

1. Pure Einstein gravity reduced on a $d$-dimensional torus $T^d$ has an $GL(d)$ symmetry, and the scalars occupy the coset $\frac{GL(d)}{SO(d)}$.
2. Heterotic supergravity reduced on a $d$-dimensional torus $T^d$ has an $O(d,d)$ symmetry (due to $T$-duality), and the scalars occupy the coset $\frac{O(d,d)}{O(d)\times O(d)}$.

Why do the scalars occupy $G/K(G)$?